# Linux QT5 DPI scale issue

Tags: linux, qt5, xfce, hidpi

OS: OpenSuSE TumbleWeed, XFCE 4.14, with HiDPI display, Font size @144DPI

**GTK Programs UI are all fine.**

### QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1

if set in `/etc/environment`

```
QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SET_FACTOR=0
QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.00
```

kate, keepassxc, KAddressBook, KTnef, KNotes... UI fonts are HUGE, like (144 * 144/96) DPI that huge, redundantly scaled.

KSuduku, KCalc, KCharSelect... UI font size are as expected.

### QT_SCALE_FACTOR=0.75

if set in `/etc/environment`

```
QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SET_FACTOR=0
QT_SCALE_FACTOR=0.75
```

kate, keepassxc, KAddressBook, KTnef, KNotes... UI fonts are fine.

KSuduku, KCalc, KCharSelect, SMplayer, QPdfView... UI are corrupted. Menu items shifted, element and font size/position not match, elements overlapped...

[image: SMplayer]

[image: KCharSelect]

Comment: Try `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0`

Comment: Setting QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR to 0 does not solve the problem (which I have as well). Did you find a solution OP?